# Is it possible to know the last call date to specific contact in iPhone by programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, cal

Is it possible to know the last call date to specific contact in iPhone by programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO.**

You can't access the call details and message details programmatically.

If you do so apple will reject your app, also you can do it on jailbroken device.

If you are looking for jailbroken devices: [**Accessing iPhone Call History**](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/), anyway I won't recommend it.

Comment: But in  my application it is the main requirement..any alternative solution is there?

Comment: @user2020562: I think no, or you need to wait till Apple release their API for doing this.

Comment: @user2020562: check this link too : http://avi.alkalay.net/2011/12/iphone-call-history.html

Comment: @ Midhun:I found one alternative solution for this...If user make a call using our app then we can get the last call time, date  and duration also .But I need to implement the call functionality in the app.

Comment: @user2020562: Thanks for the information. Please post it as your answer, so that we can use refer it in future :)